# SAPUI5 - [50053] - Incomplete dimensions binding

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm trying to create a bar chart on SAPUI5 with JSON Data and I have this error : [50053] - Incomplete dimensions binding. According different posts, the error is linked with the names in the FeedvaluesAxis and the Dataset. In my case when I look at my code the two name are similar.

my Bar.Controller.js :

```
    sap.ui.controller("dataxml.Bar", {


onInit: function() {


        var oVizFrame = this.getView().byId("idcolumn");


        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        var data = [{
            "orderid":"1",
            "productname":"Coca",
            "price":"5",
            "launchdate": "20180505",
            "categorie":"1"
    },{
            "orderid":"2",
            "productname":"Ice Tea",
            "price":"8",
            "launchdate": "20180505",
            "categorie":"1"
    },{
            "orderid":"3",
            "productname":"Pepsi",
            "price":"4",
            "launchdate": "20180506",
            "categorie":"1"
    },{
            "orderid":"4",
            "productname":"Coca",
            "price":"5",
            "launchdate": "20180506",
            "categorie":"1"
    },{
            "orderid":"6",
            "productname":"Mango",
            "price":"1",
            "launchdate": "20180605",
            "categorie":"1"
    }]
        oModel.setData(data);


        var oDataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
            dimensions : [{
                    name : "orderid",
                    value : "{orderid}"},{
                    name : "productname",
                    value : "{productname}"},{
                    name : "launchdate",
                    value : "{launchdate}"}],

            measures : [{
                name : "price",
                value : "{price}"},{
                name : "category",
                value : "{category}"
                }],

            data : {
                path : "/"
            }
        });     
        oVizFrame.setDataset(oDataset);
        oVizFrame.setModel(oModel); 


        oVizFrame.setVizType('column');
        oVizFrame.setVizProperties({
            plotArea: {
                colorPalette : d3.scale.category20().range()
                }});

        var feedValueAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
              'uid': "valueAxis",
              'type': "Measure",
              'values': ["price"]
            }), 
            feedCategoryAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
              'uid': "categoryAxis",
              'type': "Dimension",
              'values': ["productname"]
            });
        oVizFrame.addFeed(feedValueAxis);
        oVizFrame.addFeed(feedCategoryAxis);

        }
```

my index.html :

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>

    <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
    </script>
    <!-- only load the mobile lib "sap.m" and the "sap_bluecrystal" theme -->

    <script>
            sap.ui.localResources("dataxml");
            var app = new sap.m.App({initialPage:"idBar1"});
            var page = sap.ui.view({id:"idBar1", viewName:"dataxml.Bar", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});
            app.addPage(page);
            app.placeAt("content");
    </script>

</head>
<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

my bar.view.xml :

```
    <core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="dataxml.Bar" 
    xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<Page title="Bar char">
    <content>
    <FlexBox justifyContent="Center" alignItems="Start">                
      <items>
        <viz:VizFrame xmlns="sap.viz" id="idcolumn">
        </viz:VizFrame>         
     </items> 
    </FlexBox>
    </content>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you tell me why you add a different amount of dimensions and measures to the dataset (Dimensions 3 & Measures 2) and feed (Dimensions 1 & Measures 1)? You could try adding the rest like this?

Btw, the model data says '**categorie**' and the dataset '**category**'? That might make a difference as well.

```
    var feedValueAxis1 = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
            'uid': "valueAxis",
            'type': "Measure",
            'values': ["price"]
        });

        var feedValueAxis2 = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
            'uid': "valueAxis",
            'type': "Measure",
            'values': ["category"]
        });

        var feedCategoryAxis1 = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
            'uid': "categoryAxis",
            'type': "Dimension",
            'values': ["orderid"]
        });

        var feedCategoryAxis2 = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
            'uid': "categoryAxis",
            'type': "Dimension",
            'values': ["productname"]
        });

        var feedCategoryAxis3 = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
            'uid': "categoryAxis",
            'type': "Dimension",
            'values': ["launchdate"]
        });

        oVizFrame.addFeed(feedValueAxis1);
        oVizFrame.addFeed(feedValueAxis2);
        oVizFrame.addFeed(feedCategoryAxis1);
        oVizFrame.addFeed(feedCategoryAxis2);
        oVizFrame.addFeed(feedCategoryAxis3);
```

Comment: Thank you my code works thanks to you. I didn't want to insert all the values since at first I only wanted to test. For'category', it is an error of inattention --'.

Anyway, thanks for your help.